# How do i set the HTML tag's “background” property with JS, still allowing other properties from a CSS file to be unchanged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had some CSS in a seperate .css file for my site that went as follows:

```
html {
    background: url("images/1080 Native2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    height: 100%;
}
```

This works, and i wanted to keep this exact style, but have that every day, depending on the day of the month, the background image would be different. My intent was to use JS to do this with jQuery, and list all the file names in an array, taking the day of the month modulo the array size to get which image to show. The script partly works in that it DOES grab the correct file name for the date, but somehow it is not writing this information to the html tag's style correctly. The following are my current HTML, CSS, and JS files:

HTML (index.php):

```html
    <html>
 <head>
        <title>ChillSpot Alpha-test 1.0.7</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> $( document ).ready( getImage );</script>
 </head>
    ... (rest of page)
```

JavaScript (background.js):

```html
    <!--

    function getImage(){
    var myimages=new Array();
    
    //specify images below.
    myimages.push("1080pAfrican.jpg");
    myimages.push("1080pDragon.jpg");
    myimages.push("1080pIndia.jpg");
    myimages.push("1080pNativeAmerican.jpg");
    myimages.push("1080pNativeAmerican2.jpg");
    
    var len = myimages.length;
    var dayOfMonth = new Date().getDate();
    var index = dayOfMonth % len;
    alert(dayOfMonth + "," + index + "," + myimages[index]);
    
    //document.write("<html style='background: url('images/" + myimages[index] + "') no-repeat center center fixed;'>");
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.background = 'url("images/' + myimages[index] + '") no-repeat center center fixed;';
    }

    //-->
```

CSS (style.css):

```html
    html {
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    
        height: 100%;
    }
```

I am using jquery-1.11.2.min.js for this

... What is wrong with my approach? I have looked up lots of things about javascript and i dont understand what is wrong. I think it may have to do with when i actually try to change the "background" attribute of the html tag, but im not sure!

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: JS will modify the in-memory style sheet. It won't change what you see in "view source", or the original .css file.

Comment: Side note: If you are going to use jQuery at all, (which you are) use it for everything. Your code will be a lot shorter. :)

Comment: Why didn't you just edit your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27786128/1169519)?

Comment: Teemu: too much bad reputation for linking my code instead of directly posting, decided to start fresh so people will actually assist instead of picking at my bones. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use jQuery at all, please use it for selectors too :)

Note: you can use a literal array instead of all the pushes.

```
function getImage(){
    var myimages=["1080pAfrican.jpg",
         "1080pDragon.jpg",
         "1080pIndia.jpg",
         "1080pNativeAmerican.jpg",
         "1080pNativeAmerican2.jpg"];

    var len = myimages.length;
    var dayOfMonth = new Date().getDate();
    var index = dayOfMonth % len;
    alert(dayOfMonth + "," + index + "," + myimages[index]);

    $('html').css('background-image', 'url("images/' + myimages[index] + '")');
}
```

Comment: Note: dPerry's suggestion works as well, and is equivalent to this one. The reason i accepted this answer was because the exact code including the url() function was included. For some reason i was being an airhead and didnt include this while trying dPerry's suggestion, so it helped alot to see the full source in this answer. Thank you TrueBlue! :)

Answer (score 2):

set the image using just the `background-image` property.

static css:

```
html {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

then in your script, just do

```
$('html').css('background-image', 'url("images/' + YOUR_SELECTED_IMAGE + '")');
```

Comment: I would like to try this, the "background" property is a short hand to allow you to specify more than just the image url. Do you know what equivalent CSS is for "background: url("images/1080 Native2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;" would be? If i had that i would declare the other properties as static in CSS and use your suggestion!

Comment: Tried your current suggestion with "$('html').css('background-image', 'images/' + myimages[index]);" and this is not working for me with waterfox. Image is blank.

Comment: my mistake, i forgot to wrap my image in url(). Your solution DOES work, it was just ignorance on my part when testing, thanks!

Comment: Marked this answer as "useful", as it is deserved and this answer IS correct. Thank you once more.

Comment: yeah, I should have included the url wrapper too. added to answer for future generations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.background = "url('images/" + myimages[index] + "') no-repeat center center fixed;";
```

I think you were having problems with the order of your single and double quotes.

Comment: I hate to admit it brso05, but i think you are very likely correct. Let me try your solution....

Comment: @Drifter64 I ran just this line of code with an image from google and it works

Comment: Unfortunately, this isnt working for me. I am running waterfox, and the background is blank, although you can see from the Alert() that the right image is gotten (1080pAfrican.jpg, if it is monday Jan 5th for you right now).